# ADB doesn't recognize a Samsung GT-I9000

Tags: debian, usb, adb, samsung

I've connected the phone via USB. The phone is rooted, USB debugging is enabled and ADB has root access. The system is a vanilla Debian 8.3.0.

`lsusb`:

```
[...]
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04e8:685e Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9100 Phone [Galaxy S II] (USB Debugging mode)
```

`adb devices`:

```
List of devices attached
```

`adb shell`:

```
error: device not found
```

The same occurs when I run the commands as root.

How can I connect to the phone with `adb`?

Comment: in the original rom it used to need an udev rule like `ATTR{product}=="SAMSUNG_Android", OWNER="yourname"` to solve permission issues

Comment: That worked! I've added `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666", OWNER="<username>"` to `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`..
If you'll post an answer, I'll accept it. cheers!

Comment: @boolean.is.null where you have `<username>` do I just write it like that or replace with some username? Also, with `MODE=` or `OWNER=` do you mean to use a single `=` or double `==` ?